# A table that consists of multiple FK or creating separate tables for each FK

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have tables called 'books', 'category', 'subcategory', and 'booksCategory'. Each book can have its own category and subcategories.
For example, a Sci-Fi book can belong in the 'category' table under sci-fi, but it also may be under the subcategory under 'Aliens'.

- Table books -  a list of books
- Table Category - a list of categories. e.g. Sci-Fi
- Table Subcategory - a list of subcategories. e.g. Aliens
- Table booksCategory - a list of books under categories and subcategories

I wasn't sure of the most optimal way of creating booksCategory. 
booksCategory will have a FK referencing the ids of both Category and Subcategory tables.

```
CREATE TABLE booksCategory(
  booksCategory_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
  category_id INT references category (category_id),
  subcategory_id INT references subcategory (subcategory_id)
)
```

so the results would be something like this

```
booksCategory_id | category_id | subcategory_id | books_id
----------------------------------------------------------
     1                 3            4                 1     // 3 = SCI-FI, 4 = Aliens
     2                 2            NULL              1    // 2 = Adventure, Null = does not belong to any subcategory
```

The problem occurs when a book falls under multiple categories. In the example above, book_id with 1 can be both SCI-FI and Adventure. Is this the best method because then I will have a NULL in subcategory?

My other option I can think of is to have separate tables for booksCategory, booksSubcategory, and if I have more subcategories, bookSubcategories2.  So basically a separate list of books that fall under Category, another list of books that fall under subcategory, and if I have more branching subcategories, a list of books that fall under that subcategory. I'm not really too fond of this method because it seems less organized/scattered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you desire a categorization hierarchy of indeterminate depth, you will have to use a single category table structured along these lines:

```
CREATE TABLE Category (
    Category_ID           INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    Parent_Category_ID    INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Category(Category_ID),
    Description           varchar(255) not null
)
```

This type of structure is not as well supported by **MySQL** as some other RDBMS's, but these issues can all be worked through.

You will also need a revised BookCategory mapping table such as this:

```
CREATE TABLE BookCategory (
    Book_ID        INT NOT NULL references Book(Book_ID),
    Category_ID    INT NOT NULL references Category(Category_ID)
)
```

My apologies if the Foreign Key syntax above is not quite correct for **MySQL**; I usually work with SQL Server.

**Update**
With this INSERT:

```
insert Category(Parent_Category_ID,Description)
values (1,'Mystery')
      ,(2,'SciFi')
      ,(2,'Aliens')
      ,(3,'Humanoid')
      ,(3,'Reptilian')
      ,(3,'Other')
;
```

the following SELECT:

```
select
    root.Category_ID,
    cast(
      coalesce(grandparent.Description + '-',' ') +
      coalesce(parent.Description + '-',' ') +
            root.Description 
    as varchar(255)) as Description
from Category                           root
left join Category                      parent
   on parent.Category_ID            = root.Parent_Category_ID
  and root.Parent_Category_ID      <> root.Category_ID
left join Category                      grandparent
   on grandparent.Category_ID       = parent.Parent_Category_ID
  and parent.Parent_Category_ID    <> parent.Category_ID
```

yields this:

```
Category_ID Description
----------- 
1             Mystery
2             SciFi
3            SciFi-Aliens
4           SciFi-Aliens-Humanoid
5           SciFi-Aliens-Reptilian
6           SciFi-Aliens-Other
```

When Common Table Expressions are supported (not yet in MySQL I understand) the following will provide automatic nesting of the hierarchy levels:

```
with data as (
    select
        Category_ID,
        cast(Description as varchar(255)) as Description
    from Category
    where Parent_Category_ID = Category_ID

    union all

    select
        child.Category_ID,
        cast(parent.Description + '-' + child.Description as varchar(255)) as Description
    from data       parent
    join Category   child
       on child.Parent_Category_ID  = parent.Category_ID
    and child.Parent_Category_ID <> child.Category_ID
)
select 
     Category_ID,
     Description
from data
```

Comment: You'll also need a many-to-many table between `Category` and `Book`

Comment: @ypercube: OP already has that; it seemed redundant to re-state the obvious in that circumstance.

Comment: He has it but without foreign key to `Book`!

Comment: @ypercube: Ha! That's what I get for skimming too quickly.

Comment: Oops, me too. He has it in the data but not in the code.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion above. I'm a bit slow, but I think I understand. The first table above helps link categories and subcategories together. So if Category_ID is 4 (Aliens), then Parent_Category_ID will also be 4? Or is it the other way around? Category_ID is 3 (SCI-FI) and Subcategory/Parent_Category_ID will also be 3.

Comment: @user3029001 No, if you want to mark Aliens (id=4) as a subcategory of Scifi (id=3), the row about Aliens would have `Category_ID=4, Parent_Category_ID=3, Description='Aliens'`

Comment: Check the Adjacency List model (one of the ways to represent hierarchical data.) See this question at SO: [What are the Options for Storing Hierarchical Data in a Relational Database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database) There are numerous articles on the Internet about the 4 or 5 ways to store such data.

Comment: Oh perfect, didn't know there was a term for this problem. Thanks a lot!